# When accepting an answer (or unaccepting it), the layout of the comments change

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

When I accept or unaccept an answer, the comments get "squished" in a weird manner.

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac
>   OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6)
>   Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6

Good :

[image]

Not good:

[image]

It's all coming from [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868269/how-to-create-a-method-like-findbysomethingandsomethingelse-using-ruby).

Comment: Shoot it or we shoot you!

Comment: Can't really since I have to accept an answer. I guess I can still revert that. Screenshot coming up in a sec

Comment: Is it still squished after reloading the page? Do you use zoom? Do you use a customized font?

Comment: When I reload it's fine. I don't zoom, I don't use customized fonts. It's just the JS that seems to change _something_

Comment: You should drop that and use a GreaseMonkey script instead.

Comment: Or maybe jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we added comment editing, the comment html structure changed a bit, causing some client script to behave incorrectly.

This has been fixed; thanks for submitting the bug!